# Mapping a sum across categories to an aesthetic in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that consists of several samples, combinations of two conditions, and the results of those conditions, which in this case are the number of true positives and the number of false positives.

The best way I have come up with to display this is a stacked dot plot. Here is the result for a single sample, which looks basically how I want it:

[image: Single sample stacked dot plot]

Now, what I'd like to do is sum the total true and false positives across all the samples, and plot them exactly the same way. When I try, all the dots for each sample get stacked on top of one another, instead of summed and plotted together, like this:

[image]

(Notice the bullseye pattern, where there should be just 2 circles at each point.)

Here is some smaller sample data of the same form, and the approaches I've tried, using stat_sum():

```
require(dplyr)

samples <- c(rep("Sample 1", 4), rep("Sample 2", 4), rep("Sample 3", 4))
cond1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
cond2 <- rep(c("X", "Y"))

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(samples, cond1, cond2))
data$true <- sample(30, length(data$samples))
data$false <- sample(20, length(data$samples))

data <- gather(data, type, hits, true, false)

#The good single-sample version
ggplot(filter(data, sample == "Sample 1"), aes(
    x = cond1, y = cond2, size = hits, color = type)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20)

#Trying stat_sum() across hits
ggplot(data, aes(x = cond1, y = cond2, size = hits, color = type)) +
  stat_sum(aes(group = hits), alpha =0.2) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20)

#Trying stat_sum() weighting by hits
ggplot(data, aes(x = cond1, y = cond2, size = hits, color = type)) +
  stat_sum(aes(group = 1, weight = hits), alpha =0.2) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20)
```

How can I get the sum of true and false hits across the samples, and plot them by condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming the dataset before plotting using dplyr's group_by() and summarize() works:

```
require(dplyr)
grouped_data <- group_by(data, cond1, cond2, type)
summarize(grouped_data, hits = sum(hits))

ggplot(grouped_data, aes(x = cond1, y = cond2, size = hits, color = type)) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
scale_size_area(max_size = 20)
```